# Query param not parsing while using next to path params

Tags: node.js, express, url, routes, url-routing

URL: *localhost:8000/projects/12345?isSoftDelete=1*
express format: /projects/:projectId/

parsing:

```
const projectId = request.params.projectId;
```

`projectid` is 12345

```
const isSoftDelete = request.query.isSoftDelete;
```

`isSoftDelete` is null

It is working when I add some static url between query and path params 
URL: *localhost:8000/projects/12345/Staticpath?isSoftDelete=1*

```
const projectId = request.params.projectId;
```

`projectId` is 12345

```
const isSoftDelete = request.query.isSoftDelete;
```

`isSoftDelete` is 1

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: I think he's trying to know why request.query.isSoftDelete is null in his first mentioned case where he's using params.

Comment: isSoftDelete is null, while using [DELETE]. Its working in [GET]